# What's the difference between isHidden and remove for a sub view?

Tags: ios

What is the difference between using remove from sub view vs ishidden? I need a button to be inaccessible by a user. Which is better and more secure to make sure a user does not have access to that button? What is the difference between these two methods and is there a better method for doing this other than these two mentioned here?

Comment: As simple as the keyword says-->
#1 Hidden means the view is there but will not be visible to device's screen. you can show it by setting it visible(isHidden =  false)
#2 Once we remove any view will be erased from the VC view's stack of subviews

Hope this may help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple equation is *"If you don't need the View/SubView in future, just do **removeFromSuperView** otherwise **hide** and **show** the View/SubView."*

Which one is better? Depends on your requirement. In most cases, it is better to hide a View, If you need to show again when some event occurs.

Here you go the differences:

**isHidden:**

> A hidden view disappears from its window and does not receive input
>   events. It remains in its superview’s list of subviews, however, and
>   participates in autoresizing as usual. Hiding a view with subviews has
>   the effect of hiding those subviews and any view descendants they
>   might have. This effect is implicit and does not alter the hidden
>   state of the receiver’s descendants. Hiding the view that is the
>   window’s current first responder causes the view’s next valid key view
>   to become the new first responder.

**removeFromSuperView:**

> Unlinks the view from its superview and its window, and removes it
>   from the responder chain. If the view’s superview is not nil, the
>   superview releases the view. Calling this method removes any
>   constraints that refer to the view you are removing, or that refer to
>   any view in the subtree of the view you are removing.

Answer (score 1):

`isHidden` will just hide the button and can be shown whenever necessary. If you use `remove from subView` then you are essentially removing it from memory. In this case you'll have to instantiate or create a new button when you want to show that button. In order to make it inaccessible, you can also set `isEnabled` property to false. In this way button will be shown but will not be usable.